# Simultaneous record and play from same file

Tags: iphone, audio, core-audio, audio-recording

I'm attempting to use Audio Queue Services for the first time. After reading all the documentation and playing with some sample code, I think I understand the classes pretty well and have implemented my own playback and recording application without any problems.

I need to simultaneously record and play from the same buffer, but I'm having some significant difficulty writing to a file and reading from the file at the same time. I can get the file to be played back with no problem but only for the last written buffer before the playing started. I'm hoping it's possible to continue to playback the file for as long as it's being written to. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Incase anyone is having a similar issue, there is apparently no way to do this. I've implemented this system using a ring buffer spread out over many files. While not simple to create and match, it DOES work. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: could you help me please? I need to record from an audio stream. I used the matt gallagher's AudioStreamer classes to play the stream. I somehow need to record the streams and I'm stuck here on the recording part.

Answer (score 1):

It might be worthwhile to save the captured data in your own buffers instead of writing to a file. You can then supply these buffers to the playback.

Please make sure that you add the following line from AVFoundation framework for simultaneous capture and playback:

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];

Hope this helps.